# Keep the aside column fixed width in this flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple flexbox layout for a new website.
It has a header, a nav, a cover that is out of container in full screen and the a content and an aside.

```css
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1080px;
}

#columns {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

header {
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: #6495ED;
}

#cover {
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 -135px;
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: #6495ED;
}

header #title {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
  width: 97%;
  background-color: #6495ED;
  padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 1.5% 15px 1.5%;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Content After
--------------------------------------------- */

#columns>#content {
  padding: 3%;
  width: 64%;
}

#columns>aside {
  padding: 3%;
  min-width: 24%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

footer {
  width: 94%;
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: #6495ED;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1350px) {
  #cover {
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #columns {
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }
  #columns>#content {
    width: 94%;
    padding: 3%;
  }
  #columns>#sidebar {
    width: 94%;
    padding: 3%;
    border-top: 3px solid #E64A19;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 330px) {
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 94%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- header -->
  <header id="header">
    <h1 id="title">Two Column</h1>
  </header>
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav id="menu" class="clearfix">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="cover">

  </section>
  <section id="columns">
    <!-- Main Content area -->
    <section id="content">
      <!-- your content here -->
    </section>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <aside id="sidebar">
      <!-- your content here -->
    </aside>
  </section>
  <footer id="footer" class="clearfix">
    Copyright &copy Booo
  </footer>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQzWNe

The width of the aside column fixed for desktop and tablet, 360px, then when I go under 768 px of viewport the column disappear. 
I try to replace the width in percentage with `min-width:360px` but I broke the layout.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be disappearing to me, just moving below `#content`.

Comment: Yes, I must have the aside fixed on the right but 360 px

Comment: If you don't want it to wrap (move to below content), don't use `flex-flow: wrap`. If you want one column fixed, give that column `flex: 0 0 <desired width>`. If you want it to disappear under a certain width, in your media section for that width, give it `display: none`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention the `aside` *"disappearing"* but I see it re-flowing below `#content` on smaller viewports.

If you need `aside` to be `360px` and have `#content` fill the remaining space set `flex-grow: 1;` for `#content` and tell `#sidebar` to be `360px`.

```css
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1080px;
}

#columns {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

#header,
#cover,
#footer  {
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: #6495ED;
}

#cover {
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 -135px;
}

#title {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #6495ED;
  padding: 0 1.5%;
}

#menu ul {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 1.5%;
}

#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#menu a:hover {
  color: #000;
}


/* Content After
--------------------------------------------- */
#content,
#sidebar {
  padding: 3%;
}

#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 360px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#footer {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1350px) {
  #cover {
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  #header,
  #menu {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #columns {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #sidebar {
    border-top: 3px solid #E64A19;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 330px) {
  #menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- header -->
  <header id="header">
    <h1 id="title">Two Column</h1>
  </header>
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav id="menu" class="clearfix">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="cover">

  </section>
  <section id="columns">
    <!-- Main Content area -->
    <section id="content">
      <!-- your content here -->
    </section>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <aside id="sidebar">
      <!-- your content here -->
    </aside>
  </section>
  <footer id="footer" class="clearfix">
    Copyright &copy Booo
  </footer>
</div>
```

***Note:** Improved the CSS a little.*